# Overwrite input method list in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard

My language list includes 2 languages. One of them has 2 input methods enabled. I am trying to get rid of one of them.

Here is the user language list:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $langList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
PS C:\Users\user> $langList

 LanguageTag     : en-US
 Autonym         : English (United States)
 EnglishName     : English
 LocalizedName   : English (United States)
 ScriptName      : Latin
 InputMethodTips : {0409:00020409, 0409:00000409}
 Spellchecking   : True
 Handwriting     : False

 LanguageTag     : ja
 Autonym         : 日本語
 EnglishName     : Japanese
 LocalizedName   : Japanese
 ScriptName      : Japanese
 InputMethodTips : {0411:{03B5835F-F03C-411B-9CE2-AA23E1171E36}{A76C93D9-5523-4E90-AAFA-4DB112F9AC76}}
 Spellchecking   : True
 Handwriting     : True
```

Note the input methods for en-US (`$langList[0].InputMethodTips` above). Here, the first element with value `00020409` refers to the "United States-International" keyboard, and `00020409` is the "US" keyboard.

I want to get rid of the "United States-International" keyboard and toggle between the 2 remaining input methods using the `Win+space` keyboard layout. Currently, `Win+space` is cycling through all 3 input methods.

I proceed to remove the input method through either PowerShell or the UI, the result is the same. The changes are reflected in the user language list:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $(Get-WinUserLanguageList)[0].InputMethodTips
 0409:00000409
```

and `Win+space` toggles between the US keyboard and the Microsoft IME for Japanese. All is good... Until I restart my system. After restarting the "United States-International" keyboard is once again enabled, and `Win+space` will cycle through all 3 keyboards. However, the user language list will be unchanged, still showing only one input method for en-US, and Windows Settings will also only show one input method enabled, in accord with the language list.

So, please... HOW can I get rid of this invasive keyboard/language pack/input method that refuses to die?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/1585065/168976) answer might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for! (after a year of using a hotkey workaround and 2 clean installs). To solve this issue, you must delete a few values from the registry:

First, I deleted the pertinent values from the respective keys in the User Profile and corresponding backup, found at

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\ [SID of the user in question] \Control Panel\International\User Profile\ [pertinent language code]
```

and

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\ [SID of the user in question] \Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup\ [pertinent language code]
```

What I describe above should suffice. I also deleted the value pointing at the unwanted input method from `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`, but this key should be sourced at startup with the updated settings.